# How can you get your mood when you are tripping?

Tags: meaning

There is the song by XXXTENTACION 'Moonlight' and I can't understand why he asks him to get his mood right, if he is under drug influence. And even more I don't understand why he asks him 'why he is tripping', as I see it means 'freak out, acting crazy or funny.', maybe that's the reason why he is tripping. So please tell me if he is under drugs or just have a bad mood.

> Nigga, why you trippin'? Get your mood right, uh

Can you describe that tripping nigga, I can't imagine how he looks...

Comment: It comes from psychedelic drugs where you see things that are not there. You are said to be tripping (traveling in your mind and seeing things that are not there) The term is not originally hiphop. It's from the hippie era. You closed the question too soon so...

Comment: The term originates with psychedelic drug use, but it has a slightly different meaning in the context of hip-hop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are slang terms. Outside of the context of drug use, "[tripping](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=trippin)" usually means "overreacting" or sometimes just generally acting inappropriately, but not in a fun or wild sense. "Get your mood right" simply means "change your demeanor".

Comment: Thank you. and how often do you here that in real life?

Comment: @Дмитрий They are fairly common, especially this meaning of "tripping", but their use varies with different cultural groups. People even marginally familiar with hip-hop/rap should understand the meaning, but many people do not use that kind of slang even though they understand it.

Comment: I hope I will face it again somewhere, I need more examples :)